# npm install --save web-animations-js not working

Tags: angular, npm

npm install --save web-animations-js
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/web-animations-js failed, reason: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames: "Host: reg
istry.npmjs.org. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:a.sni.fastly.net, DNS:a.sni.global-ssl.fastly.net"

Please suggest.

[certificate snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YomCi.png)

Comment: DNS:a.sni.fastly.net
DNS:a.sni.global-ssl.fastly.net

Host name is not matching with certificate CN value.

Answer (score 0):

There is a dot at the end of your npm registry URL. This is probably causing the errors. The registry URL should be: https://registry.npmjs.org/ instead of https://registry.npmjs.org./. You should fix this in your .npmrc which is probably in your home directory. You could also try running the following command:

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

[source](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/13490)

Comment: Where you saw dot in my registry url??

check this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/YomCi.png

Comment: run `npm config set strict-ssl false` and re-run `npm install --save web-animations-js`

Comment: npm verb argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--save" "web-animations-js" "--verbose"
npm verb node v8.11.4
npm verb npm  v6.4.0
npm ERR! code E500
npm ERR! 500 Internal Server Error: web-animations-js@latest
npm verb exit [ 1, true ]
npm timing npm Completed in 74069ms